# How to run a map reduce job using Java -jar command

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I write a Map reduce Job using Java.
Set configuration

```
                    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000");
        configuration.set("mapreduce.job.tracker", "localhost:54311");

        configuration.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
        configuration.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "localhost:8032");
```

Run using Different Case

case 1: "Using Hadoop and Yarn command" : Success Fine Work

case 2: "Using Eclipse " : Success Fine Work

case 3: "Using Java -jar after remove all configuration.set() " :

```
                    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        Run successful but not display Job status on Yarn (default port number 8088)
```

case 4: "Using Java -jar" : Error

```
     Find stack trace:Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1255)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1251)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1556)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1250)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1279)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
at com.my.cache.run.MyTool.run(MyTool.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at com.my.main.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

I request to you please tell me how to run a map-reduce job using "Java -jar" command and also able to check status and log on Yarn (default port 8088).

Why need: want to create a web service and  submit a map-reduce job.(Without using Java runtime library for executing Yarn or Hadoop command ).

Comment: check mapred-site.xml , is it defined as yarn

Comment: it well run using hadoop ,yarn and eclipse

Comment: so no error in  mapred-site.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's quite difficult to run hadoop application without hadoop command. You better use hadoop jar than java -jar.

I think you don't have hadoop environment in your machine. First, you must make sure hadoop running well on your machine.

Personally, I do prefer set configuration at mapred-site.xml, core-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml. I know a clear tutorial to install hadoop cluster in [here](http://milinda.pathirage.org/hadoop/yarn/2013/09/29/how-to-setup-multi-node-hadoop-20xyarn-cluster.html)

At this step, You can monitor hdfs in port 50070, yarn cluster in port 8088, mapreduce job history in port 19888.

Then, you should prove your hdfs environtment and yarn environtment running well. For hdfs environment you can try with simple hdfs command like mkdir, copyToLocal, copyFromLocal, etc and for yarn environment you can try sample wordcount project.

After you have hadoop environment, you can create your own mapreduce application (you can use any IDE). probably you need [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-basics-creating) for tutorial. compile it and make it in jar.

open your terminal, and run this command

```
hadoop jar <path to jar> <arg1> <arg2> ... <arg n>
```

hope this helpfull.

Comment: All this well and setting also. problem is i want to run map-reduce using web service. with using java runtime lib. thanks for post